# Cómo evitar que se monte mi componente a la primera?

Tags: vue3

Tengo dos componentes principales, una `Lista de resultados` y un `mapa`.
Ambos inician visibles. En la lista de resultados puede (o no) haber resultados, y en el mapa se verán marcadores.
Al hacer click en cualquier marcador, un componente debe abrirse (cubriendo por completo los resultados) y mostrar información que el marcador del mapa le provee.

Mi componente mapa, creo que no hace falta mostrarlo. Funciona bien.
Lo mismo sucede con el componente que se abre al clickear en el marcador.

El problema está en que lo llamo en el componente `<ListaResultados/>` :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <tool-bar />
  </div>
  <div class="container-principal-resultados">
    <div class="splitter-resultados p-d-flex p-ai-center p-jc-center">
      <div>
        <propiedad-marker />
      </div>
```

Yo esperaba colocar el componente ahi, y que al clickear en el marcador, este se despliegue y se muestre. Eso funciona de 10, el problema es que al cargar el sitio, el componente se monta de una (aunque no se muestre, si le pongo un `onMounted(() => {alert('hola')}` veo el alert a la primera)

Mi problema es `Donde debo colocar el componente PropiedadMarker para que no se monte a la primera`, sino que se monte al hacer click en el marcador del mapa, o bien, `cómo evitar que se monte al iniciar`

> Por las dudas adjunto el componente que se abre al clickear en el marcador, aunque insisto que no deberia ser util para pensar la solucion:

```
<template tabindex="0" v-on:keydown.esc="cerrarModal">
  <Sidebar
  id="foo"
  tabindex="0"
  v-on:keydown.esc="cerrarModal"
  v-model:visible="display"
  :baseZIndex="1000"
  class="p-sidebar-md"
  >
    <div
      id="toolbar"
      class="p-grid"
      tabindex="0"
      v-on:keydown.esc="cerrarModal"
    >
      <div id="tools-left" class="tools p-col-6">
        <!-- div @click="cerrarModal()" 
      tabindex="0" id="foo" v-on:keydown.esc="cerrarModal"
        class="boton" style="outline:none">
        <i><icon-base width="22" height="22" icon-name="guardar-busqueda"><IconVolver /></icon-base></i>
        Volver
      </div -->
      </div>
      <div
        id="tools-right"
        class="tools-mobile tools p-col-6"
        tabindex="0"
        v-on:keydown.esc="cerrarModal"
      >
        <router-link to="/favoritos" class="boton">
            <i
              ><icon-base width="22" height="22" icon-name="guardar-busqueda"
                ><IconCompartir /></icon-base
            ></i>
            Compartir
        </router-link>
        <router-link to="/favoritos" class="boton">
            <i
              ><icon-base width="22" height="22" icon-name="guardar-busqueda"
                ><IconFavoritos /></icon-base
            ></i>
            Añadir a Favoritos
        </router-link>
        <router-link to="/favoritos" class="boton btn-whatsapp">
            <i><icon-base
                width="22"
                height="22"
                icon-color="#FFFFFF"
                icon-name="alerta"
                ><IconWhatsapp /></icon-base
            ></i>
            <span class="desktop-hidden">Contactar</span>
            <div class="fondo-btn"></div>
        </router-link>
      </div>
    </div>

    <Button
      label=""
      icon="pi pi-times"
      @click="cerrarModal()"
      class="p-button-text"
    />

    <div v-if="item" class="card-minificha">
      <Card>
        <template #header>
          <div class="top-card">
            <div class="head-header-card">
              <div class="tags">
                <div class="tag-chip">Nuevo</div>
                <div class="tag-chip destacado">Destacado</div>
              </div>
              <!-- i class="pi pi-heart" style="fontSize: 1.5rem"></i -->
              <i
                ><icon-base
                  width="25"
                  height="25"
                  iconColor="#FFFFFF"
                  icon-name="favoritos"
                  ><IconFavoritos /></icon-base
              ></i>
            </div>

            <div class="head-footer-card">
              <div class="multimedia-propiedad">
                <span style="cantidad-fotos"
                  ><i
                    ><icon-base
                      width="18"
                      height="18"
                      icon-name="Cantidad de fotos"
                      ><IconFotos /></icon-base></i
                  >{{ item[0].imagenes.length }}</span
                >
                <span style="cantidad-videos"
                  ><i
                    ><icon-base
                      width="18"
                      height="18"
                      icon-name="Cantidad de videos"
                      ><IconVideos /></icon-base></i
                  >2</span
                >
                <span style="cantidad-360"
                  ><i
                    ><icon-base width="18" height="18" icon-name="Vista 360"
                      ><Icon360 /></icon-base></i
                  >1</span
                >
              </div>
              <div class="content-precio">
                <div class="precio">
                  <h5
                    v-if="item[0].operaciones[0].importe != '0'"
                    class="precio-propiedad"
                  >
                    {{ item[0].operaciones[0].moneda }}
                    {{ item[0].operaciones[0].importe }}
                  </h5>
                  <!-- h5 v-else class="precio-propiedad">Consulte</h5 -->
                  <span
                    v-if="item[0].propiedades.expensas != '0'"
                    class="precio-expensas"
                    ><strong>$ {{ item[0].propiedades.expensas }}</strong>
                    expensas</span
                  >
                </div>
                <span
                  v-if="item[0].reference_code != '0'"
                  class="codigo-propiedad"
                  >#{{ item[0].reference_code }}</span
                >
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="galeria-propiedad">
              <galeria-card :images="item[0].imagenes" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </template>
        <!-- template #title>
            Advanced Card
        </template -->
        <template #content>
          <div class="bottom-card">
            <p class="tipo-propiedad">
              <strong>{{ tipo }}</strong> en
              {{ item[0].ubicacion.localidad.nombre }}
            </p>
            <h4 @click="activarVisible()" class="titulo-propiedad">
              {{ item[0].ubicacion.direccion }}
            </h4>
            <!-- h4 class="titulo-propiedad">{{ item[0].ubicacion.direccion }}</h4-->
            <div class="tabla-caracteristicas">
              <div
                v-if="item[0].superficies.total != '0'"
                class="caracteristica"
              >
                <i
                  ><icon-base
                    width="25"
                    height="25"
                    icon-name="Superficie Total"
                    ><IconSupTotal /></icon-base
                ></i>
                <p class="numero-decimal">
                  {{
                    item[0].superficies.total.substring(
                      0,
                      item[0].superficies.total - 3
                    )
                  }}
                  m&sup2;
                </p>
              </div>
              <div
                v-if="item[0].superficies.cubierta != '0'"
                class="caracteristica"
              >
                <i
                  ><icon-base
                    width="25"
                    height="25"
                    icon-name="Superficie Cubierta"
                    ><IconSupCubierta /></icon-base
                ></i>
                <p class="numero-decimal">
                  {{ item[0].superficies.cubierta }} m&sup2;
                </p>
              </div>
              <div
                v-if="item[0].propiedades.dormitorios != '0'"
                class="caracteristica"
              >
                <i
                  ><icon-base width="25" height="25" icon-name="Dormitorios"
                    ><IconDormitorios /></icon-base
                ></i>
                <p>{{ item[0].propiedades.dormitorios }}</p>
              </div>
              <div
                v-if="item[0].propiedades.toilette != '0'"
                class="caracteristica"
              >
                <i
                  ><icon-base width="25" height="25" icon-name="Baños"
                    ><IconBanios /></icon-base
                ></i>
                <p>{{ item[0].propiedades.toilette }}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </template>
        <!-- template #footer>
            <Button icon="pi pi-check" label="Save" />
            <Button icon="pi pi-times" label="Cancel" class="p-button-secondary" style="margin-left: .5em" />
        </template -->
      </Card>
    </div>
  </Sidebar>
</template>

<script>
import IconBase from "@/components/IconBase.vue";
import IconGuardarBusqueda from "@/assets/iconos/icono-guardar-busqueda.vue";
import IconAlerta from "@/assets/iconos/icono-alerta.vue";
import IconWhatsapp from "@/assets/iconos/icono-whatsapp.vue";
import IconFavoritos from "@/assets/iconos/icono-favorito.vue";
import IconCompartir from "@/assets/iconos/icono-compartir.vue";
import IconVolver from "@/assets/iconos/icono-volver.vue";
import IconVideos from "@/assets/iconos/icono-videos.vue";
import Icon360 from "@/assets/iconos/icono-360.vue";
import IconSupTotal from "@/assets/iconos/icono-superficie-total.vue";
import IconSupCubierta from "@/assets/iconos/icono-superficie-cubierta.vue";
import IconDormitorios from "@/assets/iconos/icono-dormitorios.vue";
import IconBanios from "@/assets/iconos/icono-banios.vue";
import IconFotos from "@/assets/iconos/icono-fotos.vue";

import { ref, computed, watch, onMounted } from "vue";
import { useStore } from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";
import Button from "primevue/button";

import Sidebar from "primevue/sidebar";

import PropiedadIndividual from "../PropiedadIndividual/PropiedadIndividual.vue";
import Galleria from "primevue/galleria";
import Card from "primevue/card";
import FotoPropiedad from "../../../assets/foto-propiedad.jpg";
import GaleriaCard from "../../Galeria/GaleriaCard.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    Button,
    Sidebar,
    IconBase,
    IconGuardarBusqueda,
    IconAlerta,
    IconWhatsapp,
    IconFavoritos,
    IconCompartir,
    IconVolver,
    IconVideos,
    Icon360,
    PropiedadIndividual,
    Galleria,
    Card,
    FotoPropiedad,
    GaleriaCard,
    IconSupTotal,
    IconSupCubierta,
    IconDormitorios,
    IconBanios,
    IconFotos,
  },
  setup() {
    const store = useStore();
    const item = ref(null);

    const display = computed(() => {
      return store.state.punteroMapa.mostrarPropiedad;
    });

    const propiedadElegida = computed(() => {
      return store.state.punteroMapa.id_seleccionado;
    });

    const propiedadesListadas = computed(() => {
      return store.state.resultadosPropiedades.resultado;
    });

    const tipo = ref("");

    const tiposPropiedad = computed(() => {
      return store.state.tiposPropiedad.tiposPropiedad;
    });

    onMounted(() => {
      alert("porq")
      // document.getElementById("foo").focus();
    });

    const cerrarModal = () => {
      store.dispatch("punteroMapa/idAction", "");
      store.dispatch("punteroMapa/mostrarPropiedadAction", false);
    };

    const fetchProp = () => {
      let url =
        "http://api.dacalbienesraices.com.ar/properties/" +
        propiedadElegida.value;
      axios.get(url).then(({ data }) => {
        item.value = data;
      });
    };

    watch(propiedadElegida, (a, b) => {
      var abriste;
      var pos = -1;

      b == "" ? (abriste = true) : (abriste = false);

      if (abriste) {
        if (propiedadesListadas.value.data !== undefined) {
          let res = propiedadesListadas.value.data.propiedades;
          res.forEach((e, index) => {
            if (e.idd == propiedadElegida.value) {
              pos = index;
            }
          });

          if (pos != -1) {
            item.value = res[pos];
          } else {
            fetchProp();
          }
        } else {
          fetchProp();
        }
        setTimeout(() => {
          tiposPropiedad.value.forEach((e) => {

            if (e.id == item.value[0].tipo) {
              tipo.value = e.nombre;
            }
          });
        }, 500);
      }
    });

    const activarVisible = () => {
      store.dispatch("propiedadPopup/mostrarPropiedadAction", true);
      store.dispatch("propiedadPopup/itemAction", props.item);
    };

    return {
      display,
      cerrarModal,
      propiedadElegida,
      item,
      tipo,
      activarVisible,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Y cual es el problema de que este creado de entrada?

Comment: @gbianchi el tema es que este componente propiedad-marker (que se despliega en un sidebar) tiene un boton. Al clickear en el, se abre un pop up que cubre toda la pantalla, con informacion mas detallada. Entonces en esta instancia tengo Un pop up, atras un sidebar y atras el sitio. Yo deseo que, al abrir cualquiera de los dos (sidebar o pop-up) se le coloque un focus, para que al tocar la tecla ESC se cierre el componente. Entonces quiero hacer ``onMounted(focus)``. Pero como se monta de una, me tira error de JS que no existe el componente para hacerle focus (esta montado pero no en el DOM)

Comment: Ahora que pienso un poco más, podria guardar una variable en la tienda cuando se muestre o no se muestre propiedad-marker, y hacer focus unicamente cuando dicha variable está en true. Voy a intentar eso.